# Print a list in Python with special formatting

Tags: python-2.7

I have 'x' list with 'n' number of elements:

```
list=[1,2,3...96,97,98...n]
```

I want to print each 3 elements from the list like this:

```
Name= 1
Last Name= 2
Number= 3

.
.
.

Name= 96
Last Name= 97
Number= 98
.
.
.

Name= n-2
Last Name= n-1
Number= n
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean besides a simple `for` loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is intended to be a database of questions and answers for programmers who may be stuck on a particular technical problem. Your question appears to be more of a "I need to write some code to perform this task, but I don't know where to start". It's very specific, and unlikely to help others in the future. This, unfortunately, is not a good fit for SO. Please may I suggest that you take a look at [ask]. If you have already made an attempt at coding this yourself, then please show your efforts and tell us how it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

User `itertools` to iterate 3 items at a time

```
from itertools import izip
l=range(1,100)
for first,second, last in izip(*[iter(l)]*3):
  print "Name: %d"%first
  print "Last Name: %d" %second
  print "Number: %d" %last
  print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = ['Name', 'Last Name', 'Number']

list = [1, 2, 3, ...]

label_index = 0
for i in list:
    print '{0}= {1}'.format(labels[label_index], i)

    if labels[label_index] == 'Number':
        label_index = -1

    label_index += 1
```